# how can I trigger fast user switching from powershell in Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I already know how to run a command/script/or another powershell as another user as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895877/how-to-switch-current-user-using-powershell

I would like to completely log in the GUI as another user, using fast user switching or equivalent. The equivalent of clicking on the user icon in the start menu in Windows 10 and clicking a username there. Which will prompt you for credentials, and start a new windows user instance for that user, keeping all your processes and windows of the current user saved behind the scenes which you could return to.

That, but type a command in powershell to trigger that user switching/other user log on.

Motivation: I can do (almost) everything in powershell. For me typing is faster than clicks. Being able to accomplish everything from one interface (in this case powershell) is efficient. Especially when rushing to finish.

Any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this with RDP - but on distance - and of course you can't both (the other user and you) be working on the PC at the same time:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c#ID0EDD=Windows_10